# Convert excel file into dictionary in python 3.5

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dictionary, openpyxl, xlrd

I am having *.xlsx file like this

```
Key   value1 value2
test1  3      5
test2  6      7
test3  6      5
```

need to convert this into dictionary like below

```
dict = {"test1":["3","5"]},{"test2":["6","7"]},{"test3":["6","5"]}
```

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel('ExcelFile.xlsx')
```

As I am new to python, your help is highly appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by "excel"? Excel is a program. Do you want to read an XLS file? Or a CSV file? Your question cannot be answered as asked.

Comment: Edited the question.

Comment: Start with `import pandas as pd` and `pd.read_excel('your/path/here.xlsx')`, then come back with an example of your data. Do you really want to have integer values as strings in your result?

Answer (score 2):

This can also be done without pandas, the `openpyxl` module lets you manipulate excel files in python::

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook

wb = load_workbook(filename='toto.xlsx')
ws = wb.active

d = {}
for row in list(ws.rows)[1:]:
    d[row[0].value] = [str(c.value) for c in row[1:]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Zip together the last two columns, and zip the first column with that.

```py
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.read_excel('Excel File.xlsx')
>>> df
    Key value1  value2
0   test1   3   5
1   test2   6   7
2   test3   6   5
>>> dict(zip(t.Key, zip(t.value1, t.value2)))
{'test1': (3, 5), 'test2': (6, 7), 'test3': (6, 5)}
```

If you want the values to be strings and not integers, check [how to change column types in Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15891038/change-column-type-in-pandas)

Comment: what is t here?